# Difference between "proscribe" and "prohibit"

Tags: differences

For a long time, I've been looking for the difference between "proscribe" and "prohibit". Unfortunately, I couldn't find any exact answer to my question, though I inferred from a passage that "prohibit" is related to law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A quick look at usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prohibit%2C+proscribe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that the two terms are used pretty much interchangeably.

If there is a difference, it is that *proscribe* is used in situations where specific actions, substances, persons, or organizations are to be placed *outside the protection of the law*.

Proscribing actions or substances in effect prohibits them. Proscriptions against people or organizations work a bit different. A person can be prohibited from being lawfully present in a geographic area by a proscription. Organizations can be prohibited from conducting meetings and recruiting members by proscription.

Answer (score 10):

The main difference between the words is that *prohibit* always carries the sense that the action is forbidden by some authority.

Proscribe, on the other hand, *can* mean "denounce or condemn", which doesn't mean that it has been outright forbidden, just very strongly disapproved, though it usually means prohibited, too.

Also, proscribe can apply to a person, while prohibit does not do so.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have addressed nuances of meaning, so I'll add more on usage. Looking in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=13048577), *prohibit* is much more commonly used: it occurs almost 40 times as often as *proscribe*.

*Prohibit* also occurs across [a variety of sources](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=13048362), though it is uncommon in fiction and most common in academic writing. *Proscribe* occurs [most in academic writing](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=13048354) and is uncommon anywhere else.

So, if choosing between the two, *prohibit* would be a more familiar choice.

Some examples from COCA:

> Egregious use of hateful words can be punished under most existing codes that *proscribe* harassment, intimidation, or threats of violence. [Magazine]
> Marxist teaching does not *proscribe* religion, but rather considers religion to be primitive and superstitious, and predicts that religion will tend to disappear... [Academic]

> Six states and the District of Columbia broadly *prohibit* employers from discriminating on the basis of breastfeeding activities... [Academic]
> ...the U.S. Department of Education will propose rules that will *prohibit* certain colleges from receiving federal financial aid... [News]

In many cases, *[prohibit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prohibit)* can be substituted for [*proscribe*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proscribe), but it doesn't always work the other way around. While both words are transitive, with *prohibit*, we can disallow either the thing, or a person from doing the thing. We most often *proscribe* the thing or behavior.  The only example I found in COCA of *proscribing* a person from doing something was an instance of *proscribe military personnel from voting*. So, *proscribe discrimination* is fine, but ? *proscribe employers from discriminating* may not sound right.

Comment: Excellent spadework and links. I particularly like that you took the trouble to show the limited range of publication types for *proscribed*. Anyone with limited brain cells to spare for remembering both words will know which one to abandon!